# Constructing a pair of complementary sequences with the perfect differences

Tags: nt.number-theory, co.combinatorics, sequences-and-series, integer-sequences, fibonacci-numbers

- Let $F_n$ be [A000045](https://oeis.org/A000045), i.e. Fibonacci numbers. Here
  $$
  F_n = F_{n-1} + F_{n-2}, \\
  F_0 = 0, F_1 = 1
  $$
- Let $g(n,m)$ be [A257961](https://oeis.org/A257961). Here
  $$
  g(n, m) = mF_{n-1} \operatorname{mod} F_n 
  $$
- Let
  $$
  \varphi=\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}
  $$
- Let
  $$
  a_1(n)=\left\lfloor n\varphi \right\rfloor, a_2(n)=n+a_1(n)
  $$
- Let $b_1(n)$ and $b_2(n)$ be a pair of infinite complementary sequences (that is, each natural number occurs exactly once in one of the sequences) such that
- $b_1(1) = 1$ and $b_1(n)-b_1(n-m)$ belongs to $\left\lbrace a_2(m),
     a_2(m)+1 \right\rbrace$ for any $n>m>0$.
- $b_2(1) = 2$ and $b_2(n)-b_2(n-m)$ belongs to $\left\lbrace a_1(m), a_1(m)+1 \right\rbrace$ for any $n>m>0$.
- Let $c(n)$ be a characteristic function of $b_1(n)$. Obviously we have $c(a_2(n)+1)+c(a2(n)+2)=1$ and $c(k)=0$ for $k$ not of the form $a_2(n)+1$ or $a2(n)+2$.
- Let $d(n)$ be a binary sequence that encodes position of ones in $c(n)$, i.e. for $d(n)=0$ we have $c(a_2(n)+1)=1$ and for $d(n)=1$ we have $c(a_2(n)+2)=1$.

I conjecture that for $i\in\mathbb{N}$, $0<j\leqslant F_{2i}$, $0<k\leqslant F_{2i}$ sequence
$$
[k > g(2i,F_{2i}-j)]
$$
for $i, k$ fixed and $j$ variable gives $k$-th subsequence of $d(n)$ length $F_{2i}$ such that resulting subsequences of $b_1(n)$ and $b_2(n)$ satisfy the conditions given above.

Here is an example for $i=4$:

```
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]
[0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]
[0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]
[0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1]
[0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1]
[0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1]
[1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1]
[1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1]
[1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1]
[1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1]
[1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1]
[1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1]
[1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1]
[1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1]
[1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1]
[1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1]
[1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
```

Corresponding permutation in [A257961](https://oeis.org/A257961) is
$$
0, 13, 5, 18, 10, 2, 15, 7, 20, 12, 4, 17, 9, 1, 14, 6, 19, 11, 3, 16, 8
$$
which gives number of zeros in each column starting from the right side.

In other words,
$$
b_1(n) = a_2(n-1) + 1 + [k > g(2i,F_{2i}-n+1)], \\
b_1(1) = 1
$$
which gives

```
[1, 3, 6, 8, 11, 14, 16, 19, 21, 24, 27, 29, 32, 35, 37, 40, 42, 45, 48, 50, 53, 56]
[1, 3, 6, 8, 11, 14, 16, 19, 22, 24, 27, 29, 32, 35, 37, 40, 42, 45, 48, 50, 53, 56]
[1, 3, 6, 8, 11, 14, 16, 19, 22, 24, 27, 29, 32, 35, 37, 40, 43, 45, 48, 50, 53, 56]
[1, 3, 6, 9, 11, 14, 16, 19, 22, 24, 27, 29, 32, 35, 37, 40, 43, 45, 48, 50, 53, 56]
[1, 3, 6, 9, 11, 14, 16, 19, 22, 24, 27, 30, 32, 35, 37, 40, 43, 45, 48, 50, 53, 56]
[1, 3, 6, 9, 11, 14, 16, 19, 22, 24, 27, 30, 32, 35, 37, 40, 43, 45, 48, 51, 53, 56]
[1, 3, 6, 9, 11, 14, 17, 19, 22, 24, 27, 30, 32, 35, 37, 40, 43, 45, 48, 51, 53, 56]
[1, 3, 6, 9, 11, 14, 17, 19, 22, 24, 27, 30, 32, 35, 38, 40, 43, 45, 48, 51, 53, 56]
[1, 4, 6, 9, 11, 14, 17, 19, 22, 24, 27, 30, 32, 35, 38, 40, 43, 45, 48, 51, 53, 56]
[1, 4, 6, 9, 11, 14, 17, 19, 22, 25, 27, 30, 32, 35, 38, 40, 43, 45, 48, 51, 53, 56]
[1, 4, 6, 9, 11, 14, 17, 19, 22, 25, 27, 30, 32, 35, 38, 40, 43, 46, 48, 51, 53, 56]
[1, 4, 6, 9, 12, 14, 17, 19, 22, 25, 27, 30, 32, 35, 38, 40, 43, 46, 48, 51, 53, 56]
[1, 4, 6, 9, 12, 14, 17, 19, 22, 25, 27, 30, 33, 35, 38, 40, 43, 46, 48, 51, 53, 56]
[1, 4, 6, 9, 12, 14, 17, 19, 22, 25, 27, 30, 33, 35, 38, 40, 43, 46, 48, 51, 54, 56]
[1, 4, 6, 9, 12, 14, 17, 20, 22, 25, 27, 30, 33, 35, 38, 40, 43, 46, 48, 51, 54, 56]
[1, 4, 6, 9, 12, 14, 17, 20, 22, 25, 27, 30, 33, 35, 38, 41, 43, 46, 48, 51, 54, 56]
[1, 4, 7, 9, 12, 14, 17, 20, 22, 25, 27, 30, 33, 35, 38, 41, 43, 46, 48, 51, 54, 56]
[1, 4, 7, 9, 12, 14, 17, 20, 22, 25, 28, 30, 33, 35, 38, 41, 43, 46, 48, 51, 54, 56]
[1, 4, 7, 9, 12, 14, 17, 20, 22, 25, 28, 30, 33, 35, 38, 41, 43, 46, 49, 51, 54, 56]
[1, 4, 7, 9, 12, 15, 17, 20, 22, 25, 28, 30, 33, 35, 38, 41, 43, 46, 49, 51, 54, 56]
[1, 4, 7, 9, 12, 15, 17, 20, 22, 25, 28, 30, 33, 36, 38, 41, 43, 46, 49, 51, 54, 56]
```

Here is the PARI/GP prog to check it numerically:

```
a1(n) = (n + sqrtint(5*n^2))\2
a2(n) = a1(n) + n
a3(n) = a2(n) + 1
f1(n) = my(A = (1 + sqrt(5))/2); floor(2*A) - floor(n*A) - floor((2 - n)*A)
f2(n, m) = my(v1); v1 = vector(a3(m) + 1, i, f1(i)); for(i=1, m, if(bittest(n, i-1), v1[a3(i)] = 0, v1[a3(i) + 1] = 0)); my(v2, v3); v2 = select(x -> (x == 1), v1, 1); v3 = select(x -> (x == 0), v1, 1); my(A1 = 0, A2 = 0); for(i=1, #v2 - 1, for(j=i + 1, #v2, A1 += (v2[j] - v2[i])==a2(j - i) || (v2[j] - v2[i])==(a2(j - i) + 1))); for(i=1, #v3 - 1, for(j=i + 1, #v3, A2 += (v3[j] - v3[i])==a1(j - i) || (v3[j] - v3[i])==(a1(j - i) + 1))); (A1==binomial(#v2, 2) && A2==binomial(#v3, 2))
f3(n, m) = my(A = fibonacci(2*m), B = fibonacci(2*m - 1)); fromdigits(Vecrev(vector(A, i, n > ((A - i)*B % A))), 2)
test(n) = my(A = fibonacci(2*n)); sum(i=1, A, f2(f3(i, n), A)) == A
```

Is there a way to prove it?